# to increment the values inside text input - javascript

Tags: html

i want to increment the values inside of the input by one
can you guys help me as i new to javascript.
thank you and your help much appreciated

below is the code:

```js
function myFunctions() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "number");
    x.setAttribute("value", "1");
    var y = document.createElement("br");
    var z = document.createAttribute("readonly");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    document.body.appendChild(y);
    x.setAttributeNode(z);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunctions()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```js
var cnt=1;
function myFunctions() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "number");
    x.setAttribute("value", cnt);
    var y = document.createElement("br");
    var z = document.createAttribute("readonly");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    document.body.appendChild(y);
    x.setAttributeNode(z);
    cnt++;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunctions()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: ohhhhh.. thank you Bharatsing ...  :D.. appreciate it so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var count = 0;
function myFunctions() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "number");
    x.setAttribute("value", count++);
    var y = document.createElement("br");
    var z = document.createAttribute("readonly");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    document.body.appendChild(y);
    x.setAttributeNode(z);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunctions()">Try it</button>
```